# How to set mandatory DropDownButton on Flutter with Colors?

Tags: dart, flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-animation

I developed like this dropdown. Everything working fine. By default, the dropdown is not select any value. How to set red color border or something like decoration on value equal null(without select).
**my dropdown code and image**

> [image]

```
 Align(
            alignment: Alignment.bottomLeft,
            child: Container(
              child: Text('Priority',
                  style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.w400)),
            ),
          ),
          // dropBox(),
          Container(
            //  width: 200.0,
            child: ButtonTheme(
              alignedDropdown: true,
              child: DropdownButton<Priority>(
                isExpanded: true,
                value: _priorities,
                //hint: Text("Select"),
                items: priority.map((Priority value) {
                  return DropdownMenuItem<Priority>(
                    value: value,
                    child: Text(
                      value.description,
                      overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                    ),
                  );
                }).toList(),
                onChanged: (value) => setState(() {
                      priorityIndex = value.id;
                      _priorities = value;
                    }),

             style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.title,
              ),
            ),
          ),
```

**I need to like this dropdown,**

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are almost there already. You have wrapped your `DropdownButton` with a `Container` - now you only have to set its `decoration` property in order to achieve your desired styling:

```
return Container(
  decoration: BoxDecoration(
    border: Border.all(color: _priorities != null ? Colors.red : Colors.transparent),
  ),
  child: DropdownButton(
    ...
```